# Will it be correct to intregrate when answer comes in via square roots since they can be positive or negative?

Tags: definite-integrals

I tried to find the integral of the function

$$\int_0^2x(x+2)^\frac{1}{2}dx$$
I substituted $$x+2=t^2$$ but while converting limits I found $t=2,-2$ as upper limit. When integrating with these different limits I get different answers while the correct is with only positive one? Why can't the one with negative one be correct?
If I do the same for the lower limit, the same situation arises.

Comment: The substitution is either $x+2=t^2$ where $t\ge 0$, or where $t\le 0$. We are really setting $t=\sqrt{x+2}$ or $t=-\sqrt{x+2}$. Of course I prefer plus, but whichever you want to use is OK as long as you are consistent.

Comment: That you get the same answer either way is what I showed in my answer posted below. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_0^2x(x+2)^{1/2}dx
$$
If $t^2 = x+2$ then $2t\,dt = dx$ and $t^2 - 2 = x$.

As $x$ goes from $0$ to $2$, then $t^2$ goes from $2$ to $4$, so $t$ goes from${}\,\ldots\,{}$ what, to what?

We **could** let $t$ go from $\sqrt 2$ to $2$.  Then we have
$$
\int_{\sqrt 2}^2 (t^2-2) t\,(2t\,dt) = 2 \int_{\sqrt 2}^2 (t^4 - 2t^2)\,dt = 2\left[ \frac{t^5} 5 - \frac{2t^3} 3 \right]_{\sqrt 2}^2 = \frac {112 + 16\sqrt 2} {15}.
$$

**Or we could** let $t$ go from $-\sqrt 2$ to $-2$.  Then we have
$$
\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{-2} (t^2-2)(-t)(2t\,dt) = -2\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{-2} (t^4-2t^2)\,dt = - 2 \left[ \frac{t^5} 5 - \frac{2t^3} 3 \right]_{-\sqrt 2}^{-2} = \frac{112 + 16\sqrt 2}{15}.
$$

The answer is the same either way.

Comment: Why did you take **-t**.What it mean to me is that **t** is negative here and you tried to change sign and made the situation same as was with the positive limits.

Comment: @Raul : If $t^2=x+2$ then $t=\pm\sqrt{x+2}$.  If that goes from $-\sqrt2$ to $-2$, then $t=-\sqrt{x+2}$, so $\sqrt{x+2}$ is $-t$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Dont you think underroot of x+2 can itself take a negative number.It is looking as you are taking underroot of x+2 as modulus

Comment: @Raul : $x+2$ would be positive but $t$ would be negative. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\simeq$ mean "to be equal to up to a constant".
Then we have
$$
\int x(x+2)^{1/2} dx = \int \bigg[ (x+2)^{3/2} - 2(x+2)^{1/2} \bigg] d(x+2)
\simeq \frac{2}{5}(x+2)^{5/2} - \frac{4}{3}(x+2)^{3/2}.
$$
Can you complete?